# error during reading number of lines in files using futures in scala

Tags: file, scala, future, scala-collections

```
object Futures4 extends App {

  // get an array of all files in a directory tree
  def recursiveListFiles(f: File): Array[File] = {
    val these = f.listFiles
    these ++ these.filter(_.isDirectory).flatMap(recursiveListFiles)
  }

  val files = recursiveListFiles(new java.io.File("path"))

  // convert to a list of full file paths
  val fileNames = files.toList map (_.getAbsolutePath)
  println(fileNames)

  val n: Int = fileNames.length

  val futures = for {
    i <- 0 to n-1
  } yield future { line_num(i) }

  // read a file by line
  def line_num(i: Int) : Int = 
  {
    for 
    {
      line <- Source.fromFile(fileNames(i)).getLines    
      //here i am getting multiple errors saying type mismatch

    }yield line.length 
  }

  val sumF = Future.fold(futures)(0)(_ + _)
  val sum = Await.result(sumF, 2 seconds)
  println(sum)
}
```

I want to calculate the number of lines in all the files present. I am new to Scala programming so any help would be appreciated! I am getting multiple errors at one step that I have mentioned as comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line_num(i)` returns the number of lines in the file `i`. So you can write it:

```
def line_num(i: Int) : Int = {
    Source.fromFile(fileNames(i)).getLines.size
}
```

In your original function, you return a `Seq(Int)` which is the sequence of the length of each line in the file, which does not correspond to the expected return type.

Comment: Thanks alot! That did remove my error.
But when I try to run it, I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException" error. Is it maybe because my path is not correct or some other reason?

Comment: Probably not. Check the line throwing the error and check that your objects are properly instanciated.